# ORACLE 10G, I am newbie to oracle 10g. How can i syntax a query without union and view columns side by side

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to compare the titles, the qty by tradecode. The 00PAT is the order and the 553028 is the invoice. 4 TITLES order 3 TITLES sold.

```
SELECT CUS.CODE, CUS.NAME, F1.ID, F1.FTRDATE, F1.TRADECODE,MAT.SUBCODE1, MAT.DESCRIPTION, S1.PRIMARYQTY
FROM CUSTOMER CUS, FINTRADE F1, STORETRADELINES S1, MATERIAL MAT
WHERE S1.FTRID=F1.ID AND CUS.ID=F1.CUSID AND MAT.ID=S1.ITEID
AND F1.DSRID='14500' AND F1.FTRDATE='13/4/2021'
UNION   
SELECT CUS.CODE, CUS.NAME, F2.ID, F2.FTRDATE, F2.TRADECODE,MAT.SUBCODE1, MAT.DESCRIPTION, S2.PRIMARYQTY
FROM CUSTOMER CUS, FINTRADE F2, STORETRADELINES S2, MATERIAL MAT
WHERE S2.FTRID=F2.ID AND CUS.ID=F2.CUSID AND MAT.ID=S2.ITEID
AND F2.DSRID='15500' AND F2.FTRDATE='14/4/2021'

  NAME         ID   FTRDATE     TRADECODE   DESCRIPTION PRIMARYQTY
CUSTOMER1   1382757 13/4/2021   00PAT0000001    TITLE1  2
CUSTOMER1   1382757 13/4/2021   00PAT0000001    TITLE2  3
CUSTOMER1   1382757 13/4/2021   00PAT0000001    TITLE3  1
CUSTOMER1   1382757 13/4/2021   00PAT0000001    TITLE4  2
CUSTOMER1   1382766 14/4/2021   553028          TITLE2  2
CUSTOMER1   1382766 14/4/2021   553028          TITLE3  1
CUSTOMER1   1382766 14/4/2021   553028          TITLE4  2
```

[desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvefu.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data, output that you would expect from that sample data, and how that output can be achieved in plain English.  Also, please put a description/question into the question instead of just in the title.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like this:

```
SELECT cus.code,
       cus.name,
       f1.id,
       f1.ftrdate,
       f1.tradecode,
       mat.subcode1,
       mat.description,
       s1.primaryqty
FROM customer         cus
JOIN fintrade         f1  ON f1.cusid = cus.id
JOIN storetradelines  s1  ON s1.ftrid = f1.id
JOIN material         mat ON mat.id = s1.iteid
WHERE f1.dsrid IN ('14500', '15500')
  AND f2.ftrdate IN (DATE '2021-04-13', DATE '2021-04-14');
```

Comment: Thank you but the result was the same.